# Combining `raise` and `throw`

Tags: ruby, exception

I have a function:

```
def g
  ''.each_line.next
end
```

Since `each_line` returns a line iterator over an empty string, `next` raises an exception `StopIteration: iteration reached an end`.

On top of this, I have another function:

```
def f
  catch :aSymbol do
    loop do
      g
    end
  end
end
```

`catch` will catch the symbol `:aSymbol` if it is thrown somewhere, which is not the case, so this function should raise the same exception. However, calling `f` doesn't do so; it behaves, as if the `catch` would silently rescue the exception too. Is this the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is nothing to do with catch - the behaviour can be observed with

```
def f
  loop do # Loop will abort during first iteration
    g
  end
end
```

This is because [`loop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) rescues `StopIteration` and interprets that to mean that you want to break out of `loop` (see definition of [loop](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_2/vm_eval.c#L1097))

Comment: hah, and I stared at instruction sequence for good 5 minutes :)

Comment: Waaaaaahhhh! This should really go into the *documentation* of `loop`, because the behaviour is not at all obvious!

Comment: I just noticed that it is documented with `StopIteration`, but not with `loop`...